# Extract all sequential subsets from a given set

Tags: c#, math

I need to get sequential subsets (self-made terminology) for a given set. For instance, if my set is {1,5,8,25}, the output should be:

```
{1}
{5}
{8}
{25}
{1,5}
{5,8}
{8,25}
{1,5,8}
{5,8,25}
{1,5,8,25}
```

I tried implementing the same in C# lists using iterative approach but found the time complexity to be high. Can anyone help me with this?

As per comments, here is my approach which is similar to the posted answer:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> input = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

            var output = GetSubset(input);

            foreach (var element in output)
            {
                Console.Write("{ ");

                foreach (int e in element)
                {
                    Console.Write(e + " ");
                }

                Console.Write("}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<List<int>> GetSubset(List<int> arr)
        {
            List<List<int>> sets = new List<List<int>>();

            var length = arr.Count;

            // No of element on each set
            for (int k = 1; k <= length; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= length - k; i++)
                {
                    List<int> set = new List<int>();

                    for (int j = i; j < (i + k); j++)
                    {
                        set.Add(arr[j]);
                    }

                    sets.Add(set);
                }
            }

            return sets;
        }
```

As correctly pointed out, the time complexity is O(n^3). Is there a better approach towards same.

Comment: seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: also: seems to me that with that task, you can't really get a better time compexity than `O(n²)` - since for every item in your list, you have to interact once with every _subsequent_ item in your list.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should sort you out if it's fast enough:

```
IEnumerable<int[]> GetSequentialSubsets(int[] data)
{
    Array.Sort(data);

    //The number of elements to add to each returned array
    for (int m = 1; m <= arr.Length; m++)
    {
        //The starting index in int[] data of the current array
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length - m; i++)
        {
            var element = new int[m];

            //Adding data to the current array
            for (int j = i; j < i + m; j++)
            {
                element[j - i] = arr[j];
            }

            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I sort the array, just in case you throw in something unsorted. But if you don't care about incrementing elements and just want the elements to be sequential, you should leave that part out. I didn't find that part of your question entirely clear. You can test it like this:

```
var arr = new[] { 1, 5, 8, 25 };

var res = GetSequentialSubsets(arr);

foreach (var element in res)
{
    foreach (int e in element)
    {
        Console.Write(e + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The complexity must be the number of indices we iterate over which is equal to

```
n * (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 6
```

so O(n³).

N.B. The number of indices is the sum of i * (n + 1 - i) from i = 1 to i = n. WolframAlpha then gives the result above.